# Reduce the region of a GPKG dataset in R

Tags: r, geopackage, region, reduceregion

I downloaded a GPKG file (from [humdata.org](https://data.humdata.org/organization/kontur?q=italy&sort=if(gt(last_modified%2Creview_date)%2Clast_modified%2Creview_date)%20desc&ext_page_size=25)), with the population density (H3 Hexagons) of a country; the content of the dataset is the following:

```
fid [integer]: record order in data upload

h3 [h3index/text]: H3 index of hexagon

population [double]: total population inside hexagon

geom [geometry]: Polygon, EPSG:3857
```

I want to create a map of the population density using R, but I'm interested only in a smaller region, not the whole country. How can I reduce the dataset? There is a package that does the job for the states of the US, but I couldn't find a similar or more generic package.

Comment: If you want to calculate population density, you'll also need to reproject the geometry, since the area in Web Mercator will be somewhere between *very wrong* and *heinously wrong*.

Comment: My knowledge of the topic is very limited and I can't fully understand your comment, but thanks. My idea was to plot over each hexagon an height corresponding to the population inside that hexagon, which should have the same size (400 mt); I did this [map](https://ibb.co/k8fZHJc) for Florida, with a package of R that selects US states.

Answer (score 0):

You've not said how you want to define your region. If you have a bounding box in the coordinate system, you can filter out using an SQL `query` argument to `st_read`. For example, this gets all features where the X coord of the centroid is over 2004000 and the Y coord is over 4400000.  You can add "less than" bits as well to narrow down to a box:

```
h = st_read("./kontur_population_IT_20220630.gpkg", 
    query= "select *,st_x(st_centroid(geom)) as x,
            st_y(st_centroid(geom)) as y 
            from population where x > 2004000 and y > 4400000")
```

This example only returns about 3000 features.

If you want to cut to an irregular area defined by another spatial feature (eg a sub-national boundary of a national data set), then you can use `st_intersects` to test for intersection of your sub-national boundary with the hexagon set, and then subset rows on that.

Comment: Thank you, your comment is very helpful. For what I currently need, the first method could work, but in general I would be interested in a precise irregular area, so the second suggestion is very helpful too! I will try both ways.